# Redirect 'Exceptions in Oracle stored Procedure' to a log file when executing

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, jobs, job-scheduling

I have a scheduled job that runs stored procedure on daily basis at 3:00:00 AM.

I have Exception block in my procedure like below.

```
EXCEPTION
 WHEN NOT_LOGGED_ON THEN
 dbms_output.put_line('Database is not connected/Database connection is lost');
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
 dbms_output.put_line('Error in execution');
```

I want to log exceptions(if any) into some kind of log file everyday when the job runs.
So that, user can check the log file later to know whether the procedure has ran successfully or not.

Can any one please tell me is there any approach to achieve this ?

Comment: Does it have to be a file, or would logging to a table work for you? Either way you need a logging procedure you can call, which either does `utl_file` calls, or writes to a table (with an autonomous pragma, probably, so records are kept if the job rolls back). You aren't really trapping exceptions like that though are you - you at least re-raise them after 'logging'? The job log should tell you what exceptions you got in that case?

Comment: I think writing into table would be good approach for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

SO when you're doing that, and the exception is not being brought to the user - Oracle creates a dump file with the exception.

look at the udump/bdump directories - you'll probably find plenty of traces that report these errors (for jobs - looks for the dump file names that have j0... in them).

A better approach (and I can believe I'm saying it since I don't really like this mechanism) is to use the schedule jobs (dbms_scheduler) instead (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN12501) it has an internal mechanism that put all these exceptions in a table that you can query.

And if although what I wrote above - you still want to create a file...

Look for UTL_FILE ....